# after pressing home keyboard is not hiding

Tags: android, android-keypad

I use following code to show keyboard

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,
        InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

I use following code to hide keyboard `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);`

to hide keyboard, and

also tried for this

```
InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

but after pressing the home key. apps closes but keyboard remain same on the screen.

please guide me. what am I doing wrong?

I have put my hiding code.
I put hide in `onDestroy()`, `onBackPressed()` and also `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`  Sorry For my code formatting.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);

    textTv=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,
    InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);

    if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null)
    {
        Bundle extra=getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extra!=null)
        {
            // code
        }
    }
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(noteTv.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu1:
    //code
    break;
    case R.id.menu2:
    //code
    break;
```

}

Comment: You have used all the possible cases, every one will work, If it is not worked for you mean there might be some problem in your code, so show us the code where you hide your keyboard.

Comment: I have put showing code in `onCreate()` method and hiding code into `onBackPressed()`works properly . but when I pressed home key with showing keypad its not hided. @Pragnani

Comment: I have put hide code where I not to hide keyboard. @Pragnani

Comment: sorry I didn't get you. I have posted answer check that once

Comment: I have tried this but not working.. I have put some code where I am calling hiding code. @Pragnani

Comment: Sorry for formatting of code. I always try to format code properly. but I don't know how to format it. @Pragnani

Comment: you can use ctrl+k to format the code, And  why did you kept the code to hide keyboard every where..? Post your complete code, because don't need to put the code to hide keyboard everywhere.

Comment: Thanks to tell how to format. ok. then where should I put keypad hiding code. @Pragnani

Comment: It will helpful for us, if you post your complete code, so that we can identify your problem.

Comment: I have put my all code where I call hiding method. & thanks to tell how to format code.. Please check this. @Pragnani

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26285/discussion-between-pragnani-and-psk)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(noteTv.getWindowToken(), 0);
    super.onPause();
}
```